# using :reject_if to check for empty field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-2

In Rails 2.3.5 model I am using

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }
```

But its rejecting if there is the textbox is not empty..
How can I make it to reject only if there is nothing entered into the textbox ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but the code you're showing will cause the question's attributes to be ignored when a question's content is empty, nil, or otherwise blank. Is this not what you are finding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you confusing reject_if with record validation?  The reject_if merely tells the app to ignore that set of nested attributes if a condition is true.  In your case, the question's attributes will be ignored if the question's content is blank.   If you want to validate or otherwise ensure that the question record(s) have a non blank value for content, you'd put validation in your question model.

*You also might consider changing lambda{} to  proc{}.*

Answer (score 1):

reject if will save the parent object and any other amount of child objects rejecting only those that fail the reject_if condition.  If this is what you want then it is fine, i suggest debugging a little bit, put in a print statement or something, maybe

lambda { |a| puts a.inspect; a[:content].blank? }

If you want the whole nested object to save all at once, then use validations.